# nginx sites available not loading correct domain

Tags: nginx

I have several domains working fine on an nginx. I'm trying to add another one now, but it keeps bringing up another domain.

This is one of the sites available config files, the on that always loads when trying to enter the new domain.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name   www.domain1.com;
    return       301 http://domain1.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   80;

    root /data/domain1.com/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain1.com;

    error_log /data/domain1.com/logs/error.log error;
    access_log /data/domain1.com/logs/access.log;



    location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

}
```

And this is the one I'm using for the new one:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name   www.domain2.com;
    return       301 http://domain2.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   80;

    root /data/domain2.com/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain2.com *.domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    error_log /data/domain2.com/logs/error.log error;
    access_log /data/domain2.com/logs/access.log;



    location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

}
```

If I remove the first file, the new domain loads fine.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the logs when you start nginx with the new domain added? Also there is overlap between the `server_name` values in the two stanzas. Don't do that; if you want to redirect `www.domain2.com` to `domain2.com` then don't also have `www.domain2.com` in the server_name list for `domain2.com`.

Comment: @wurtel no, no errors